# split fraction is not working to split equation over multiple lines

Tags: amsmath, ieeetran, mathtools

I am trying to split a long fraction over multiple lines. I am using mathtools package and split fraction to split the long denominator. However, it doesn't seem to be working , see the attached image. Following is the complete code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, draftclsnofoot, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads 'amsmath' package automatically
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \dfrac{A_{xy,\text{MN}}^{p}}{[![\splitdfrac][1]][1]{\Gamma^{2}+{ {\sum_{x_{p}\in \Phi_{p}^{\mathcal{U}^{e}}\backslash d_{p}} \beta {{A}_{t,p}^{MN}}g_{x_{p}}^{\mathcal{U}^{e}}\lVert x_{p}\rVert^{-\alpha}}+{\sum_{y_{q}\in\Phi_{q}^{\mathcal{U}^{c}}} {{A}_{t,q}^{MN}}g_{y_{q}}^{\mathcal{U}^{c}}\lVert y_{q}\rVert^{-\alpha}}}+{{\sum_{{z_{p}}\in\Phi_{u}^{\mathcal{U}^{e}}\backslash {_\text{XYZ}}}}} {{A}_{u}^{UL}}g_{z_{p}}^{\mathcal{U}^{e}}\lVert {z_{p}\rVert^{-\alpha}}+{\sum_{{w_{q}}\in\Phi_{u}^{\mathcal{U}^{c}}}} {{A}_{u}^{UL}}g_{w_{q}}^{\mathcal{U}^{c}}\lVert {w_{q}\rVert^{-\alpha}}}, \text{for Downlink }} 
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As Mico says, where did you get this `{[![\splitdfrac][1]][1]` from? That makes no sense anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Omitting some parts (such as `\text{for Downlink}`) that seem to be extraneous, I came up with the following possible solution.

[image]

I can't help but remark that your code contains many more pairs of curly braces than the code below does. In math mode, encasing material in extra pairs of curly braces isn't entirely innocuous; plus, it sure makes parsing the code a lot more tedious than should be the case. Also, I've replaced the instances of `\backslash` with `\setminus`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, draftclsnofoot, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \dfrac{A_{xy,\text{MN}}^{p}}{%
    \splitdfrac{% first part of splitdfrac to follow
    \Gamma^{2}
    +\sum_{x_p\in \Phi_p^{\mathcal{U}^e}\setminus d_p}
      \beta A_{t,p}^{\text{MN}} g_{x_p}^{\mathcal{\,U}^e}
      \norm{x_p}^{-\alpha}
    +\sum_{y_q\in\Phi_q^{\mathcal{U}^c}}
      A_{t,q}^{\text{MN}} g_{y_q}^{\mathcal{\,U}^c}
      \norm{y_q}^{-\alpha}}{% 2nd part of splitdfrac to follow
    +\sum_{z_p\in\Phi_{u}^{\mathcal{U}^e}\setminus\text{XYZ}}
      A_u^{UL} g_{z_p}^{\mathcal{\,U}^e}
      \norm{z_p}^{-\alpha}
    +\sum_{w_q\in\Phi_{u}^{\mathcal{U}^c}} 
      A_{u}^{UL}g_{w_q}^{\mathcal{\,U}^c}
      \norm{w_q}^{-\alpha}}
    }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```